# Stopping a process in Metasploitable 2

Tags: linux

I am trying to stop MySQL in metasploitable 2. I have tried using 'sudo service mysql stop' and 'sudo systemctl stop mysql', but they both don't work. How can I stop it? Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: How does it not work, do you get any error-msg or other feedback when executing the commands?

Comment: It simply says: command not found. For both. @MangoNrFive